# How to stop function's list-type argument with default value from holding value on subsequent calls?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function that recursively calls itself to pull out and return things from a dictionary with multiple levels of nested objects (dicts, lists, and other flat [int/string/etc.] data types). At the end of it, it returns a flat 2D list of particular object names, and to do that, the function has an argument that stores the list which is passed to nested calls which then return it with the things it found appended to the list. When called by the user they shouldn't need to pass anything in to set this argument, and the default value for it is an empty list `[]`. However, when I call this function more than once, the list keeps its contents and I end up getting the next call's items appended to the previous calls' results.

That explains the why and the issue. Below is a very simple example function that demonstrates this, without the nested calls:

```
def test(arg1=[]):
    arg1.append('bob')
    return arg1
```

Calling this multiple times results in:

```
a=test()
a=test()
a=test()
print(a)
>>['bob', 'bob', 'bob']
# Whereas I am expecting it to return:
>>['bob']
```

I can change the function to below which works around the issue, but I'd like to know the proper way to do this? (or if this *is* the proper way? - feels kinda dopey)

```
def test(arg1=[]):
    arg1.append('bob')
    arg1_ = arg1
    arg1 = []
    return arg1_
```

Comment: Thanks, yep that make sense, especially when reading that attached article in the highest rated comment (http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm). So looks like the best answer is to replace the `def(arg1=[])` with `def(arg=None)` and then assigned it to `[]` if it's `None`. Jakob just beat me to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default parameters are mutable in Python, you can think of them as belonging to the global scope. You want this:

```
def test(arg1=None):
    if arg1 is None:
        arg1 = []

    arg1.append('bob')
    return arg1
```

Comment: Although the solution is good, I think some of the phrasing is misleading. "Default parameters are mutable in Python," well no, that's a category error. Default parameters are evaluated *once*, when the function is defined. So it will be the same object every time the default is used. Of course, if you mutate a mutable object, that change will happen. And I don't think it is useful of thinking of them as belonging to the global scope. The certainly do not. Scope just doesn't seem relevant.